# How to grant access to sublocations when root location is protected by htauth in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, http-basic-authentication

I have the following site configuration

```
<Location />
    AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
</Location>
```

which restricts access to all locations. Now I want to exclude say `media/`

```
<Location /media>
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

and also `upload/` which is in another directory

```
Alias /upload/files/ /another/path/upload/files/
<Directory "/another/path/upload/files/">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    ForceType text/plain

    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Unfortunately it still prompts me for authentication.

Comment: Try putting Location /media before Location /.   For /upload/files, you have no Location, so it may take the specs of Location /.

Comment: Still having the same result. It's prompting for user and pass.

Comment: Well, with only a couple of extracts from your Apache configuration, it's hard to guess what's wrong with it.  The config could even be OK, but you forgot to reload it, there could be a cache between your browser and Apache, or your browsers cache itself, you may be addressing another server ...

Comment: This part should be sufficient. You can reproduce it. Somehow `Require all granted` is not working here. Maybe some other flags like `AllowOverride AuthConfig` are missing here. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the exceptions in the following way:

```
<Directory /media>
         Options none
         AllowOverride none
         Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After the configuration is applied the apache service must be restarted.

Comment: The <Directory>-Direktive in this notation receives a full path. Check out the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory). So Im not sure what your suggestion is about.

Answer (score 1):

As Location /media came after Location /, it inherited roots AuthType.  You should be able to overrule it:

```
<Location /media>
  AuthType None
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to accomplish this

```
<Location />
    AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthType Basic
    Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/media#
    Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/upload/files/#
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

There might be other options.